# javascript: convert two dimensional array to array of objects using the first 'row' to define properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

In order to populate a data-grid that receives array of row objects,
I am looking for a good solution to convert an array such as this:

```
[  
['country', 'population'],
['someplace', 100],
['otherplace', 200]
]
```

into an array of objects such as this:

```
[
{country: 'someplace', population: 100},
{country: 'otherplace', population: 200},
]
```

UPDATE:

this is the solution I am using so far:

```
 function arrayToRows(arr) {
var defs = [];
var data = [];
var rows = [];
var r;
var obj;



var headerRow = arr.shift(); //remove header row

defs = headerRow.map(function(cell) {
  return {
    field: cell,
    displayName: cell
  }
});


for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  r = arr[i];
  obj = {};

  for (var j = 0; j < defs.length; j++) {
    obj[defs[j].field] = r[j];
  }
  rows.push(obj);
}
return rows;
```

}

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: yes, I have solved it, but interested in better solutions. will update answer with my solution....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var array = [  
    ['country', 'population'],
    ['someplace', 100],
    ['otherplace', 200]
];

var keys = array.shift();
var objects = array.map(function(values) {
    return keys.reduce(function(o, k, i) {
        o[k] = values[i];
        return o;
    }, {});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
let array = [['country', 'population'],['someplace', 100],['otherplace', 200]];
let [keys, ...rows] = array;
let result = rows.map(r => (keys.reduce((o, k, i) => (o[k] = r[i], o), {})));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey by using the library underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org/#object) you can accomplish this really easily like this:

```
var array = [['country', 'population'],['someplace', 100],['otherplace', 200]];
var output = [];

for(var index=1; index<array.length; index++){
    output.push(_.object(array[0],array[index]));
}

console.log(output);
```

Checking this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/BqA3Y/2/

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of map and forEach you can map the subsequent array elements to the columns specified in the first element.

```
var arr = [  
   ['country', 'population'],
   ['someplace', 100],
   ['otherplace', 200]
];

var cols = arr.shift();
newArr = arr.map(function(element,index){
   var newObj = {};
   element.forEach(function(data,index){
      newObj[cols[index]]=data;
   });
   return newObj;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [
    ['country', 'population'],
    ['someplace', 100],
    ['otherplace', 200]
];

var objects = [], one = array[0][0], two = array[0][1];

for (var i = 1, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    var object = {};
    object[one] = array[i][0];
    object[two] = array[i][1];
    objects.push(object);
}

console.log(objects);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/TAV2D/1/)**

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer to what was asked, if I understand the question correctly. The first row is supposed to be dynamic (not always country/population) so this would not fulfill the needs of the OP.

Comment: @Brett I thought it was just for demonstration. Nevermind, editing.

Comment: The length of the keys array is probably dynamic as well…

Comment: @Bergi Yep, I should have further modified my code, you are right, but I had gone to sleep. Nevertheless, your answer's much better !

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a bit of iteration to do this! The following code is an untested example to demonstrate what you would have to do.

```
function convertToObjectArray(table)
{
    var output = [];

    for(var i = 1; i < table.length; i++)
    {
        var obj = {};
        for(var x = 0; x < table[0].length; x++)
         obj[table[0][x]] = table[i][x];

         output.push(obj);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Another note with this example is you should edit this, however, to make sure the subsequent arrays are the same length or you could run into null values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty nicely with destructuring and `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const arr = [ ['country', 'population'], ['someplace', 100], ['otherplace', 200] ];
const [props, ...valsArr] = arr;
const res = valsArr.map(vals => Object.fromEntries(vals.map((val, i) => [props[i], val])));
console.log(res);
```

##### Explanation:

```
const [props, ...valsArr] = arr
```

This creates two new variables, `props` being the first value in your array:

```
['country', 'population']
```

and `valsArr` as being the remaining elements in your array:

```
[ ['someplace', 100], ['otherplace', 200] ]
```

Next, we use `.map()` on this array to map each inner `[place, population]` array to an array of objects. To do this, we use `Object.fromEntries()` on a mapped version of each `[place, population]` array. The mapped version of each inner array turns into:

```
[
  ["country", place],  // props[i] would be 'country' from the above `props` array
  ["population", population] // props[i+1] would be 'population' from the above `props` array
]
```

The above array of `[prop, value]` inner arrays can be passed to `Object.fromEntries()`, which will be an object for you with the keys from the first index and the values from the second index.

Answer (score -1):

```
function toObjects (array) {
  var new_array = [];
  var headers = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var obj = {};
    for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
      if(i === 0){
        headers.push(array[i][j]);
      } else {
        obj[headers[j]] = array[i][j];
      }
    }
    if(i > 0){
      new_array.push(obj);
    }
  }
  return new_array;
}
```

Comment: `['country', 'population']` is supposed to be dynamic